# How to remove the plastic taste in my backpack water bladder?

Tags: hydration

I've seen various suggestions as to how to remove the nasty plastic taste but it still seems to be the overriding taste.  I've tried bleach, vinegar, lemon juice, water purification tablets, bicarb.  I'm almost at the point of giving up and assuming that I'm ingesting carcinogenic chemicals. It isn't branded like Camelbak etc.

If anyone has any other suggestions I'm all ears.

Comment: How long have you had the bladder?  My camelback had this at first, but it passed after a few weeks of use.

Comment: Since your water-bladder isn't branded, I imagine it was cheaper and likely lower quality than one might expect from a CamelBak, etc. The bad taste may be the result of inferior plastic.

Comment: I have to agree with phsr: off-topic.

Comment: @freiheit, @pshr, re: off-topic: I disagree. Something doesn't have to be unique to cycling to count. Wicking clothing, stretching vs. warming up, hydration: these are all common issues to many activities.

Comment: Retagged: Removed "camelback" tag, this isn't a camelbak bladder, added "hydration" tag.

Comment: I've had the thing for a while now, doesn't get used all too much because of the taste though.

Fair @neilfein fair enough, but where I come from camelback is a generic term used to cover all hydration bladders.  @phsr that's pretty pedantic.

Comment: @Paul: Same here, people use "Camelbak" to mean a bladder, I just want to avoid it in tags. If it becomes an issue, we'll discuss in meta. (Yeah, it's [spelled without a C](http://camelbak.com/).)

Answer (score 3):

Denture cleaning tablets - they leave a nice minty taste as well.  Locally we have a brand called Steradent (UK & Aus only by the looks of it) that I use to clean out bidons every once in a while to get rid of either stale or detergent tastes.

Comment: In the US, a popular brand is PolyDent.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the UK so I'll pick up some Steradent and give it a go.  Otherwise the bladder is getting replaced.